# Automation of WAR/EAR deployment of maven project using Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, jenkins

Here,I am new for jenkins configuration and its use.So I want steps of jenkins automation of JAR/WAR file deployment.First Its should take update of code and then it should build that code and then deploy the jar file on server.I am using tortoise SVN as a repository.Also I want POM.xml dependencies which are required for jenkins configuration.

Comment: Not really a Java question, but what you need to do is look at build pipelines in Jenkins, and Maven plugins for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading a bit about what you're planning to do as you show no initiative or desire to try - what you described is a basic flow. Regardless:

In your job configuration under the SCM section select Subversion and add your repository information. That will handle the checking out the sources part.

Install the [Maven Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) and add your project using the information you have with the goals and parameters you need. That's handling the compilation issue.

Install [Maven Release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) and configure the following section in your pom.xml :

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://SVNServer:Port/svn/path/to/project</connection>
</scm>


<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-repository</id>
        <name>nexus repository</name>
        <url>http://Nexus_Server:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshot-repository</id>
        <name>nexus snapshots repository</name>
        <url>http://Nexus_Server:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Configure in the job configuration the Release targets for the M2 release plugin. To release you will have a Release button below the build one.

Good luck.